# learning resources for mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

i am required to use mockito to create unit testing framework for existing code. I am unable to find a good place to get started with learning Mockito. Could you please point me to a good learning resource for mockito? (online resource or otherwise)

Comment: Do you need an overview on mocking in unit-tests in general too? Mockito is an implementation of a broader technique. If a general background is required you may want to include that in your question. :-)

Answer (score 7):

In the "[Help me to start](http://groups.google.com/group/mockito/browse_thread/thread/aa2ea728440e83e8)" thread on the [mockito discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/mockito) on Google, Szczepan Faber, the project owner of mockito, suggests:

- the [Documentation](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) which includes some examples
- Brett L. Schuchert's [tutorial](http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/Mockito.LoginServiceExample)

I'd take a look at the posts in the [mockito category](http://monkeyisland.pl/category/mockito/) of Szczepan's [blog](http://monkeyisland.pl/) too.

Comment: The javadoc included with the source is pretty much all I needed to get a basic grasp of how to use it. +1

Answer (score 2):

For a overview about mock and mockito you can refer [Mockito-a-great-mock-framework-for-Java-development](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/516360/Mockito-a-great-mock-framework-for-Java-developmen)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @neminem. I thought I will not repeat the content. Yes you are correct if the link becomes invalid and it will make this answer also invalid. Down the line will try to answer it and give the reference.

Answer (score 0):

a nice succinct overview: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/mocks-and-stubs-understanding-test.html

also, take a close look at the org.mockito.Mockito class itself in the API.  most of the base behavior is held therein.