# testing service with mockito and testNG

Tags: java, maven, testng, mockito

I'm trying to test a service this is a piece of code:

```
@Test
    public void comprovarCercaBuuida(){
        /*Objecte que contindrà l'info de la cerca*/
        DeuteBackBean deuteBB;

        List<IDeute> respostaDeutesExe = new ArrayList<IDeute>();
        List<IDeute> respostaDeutesVol = new ArrayList<IDeute>();
        List<IDeute> respostaDeutesTots = new ArrayList<IDeute>();

        /*tot els paràmetres del servei s'han de passar com a mockito!!!*/
        Mockito.when(serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT),Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS),Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_EXE))).thenReturn(respostaDeutesExe);
        Mockito.verify(serveiGpt,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT), Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS), Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_EXE));

        Mockito.when(serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT),Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS),Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_VOL))).thenReturn(respostaDeutesVol);
        //Mockito.verify(serveiPersones,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).cercarPersones(Mockito.eq(PATRO_CERCA_AMB_RESULTATS), Mockito.any(IPager.class));
        Mockito.when(serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT),Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS),Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_TOTS))).thenReturn(respostaDeutesTots);
        //Mockito.verify(serveiPersones,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).cercarPersones(Mockito.eq(PATRO_CERCA_AMB_RESULTATS), Mockito.any(IPager.class));
}
```

but i found out this exception with maven: 
T

```
ests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.998 sec <<< FAILURE!
comprovarCercaBuuida(cat.base.gpt.ui.ConsultaDeutesTest)  Time elapsed: 0.078 sec  <<< FAILURE!
Wanted but not invoked:
iGptService.obtenirDeutes(
    cat.base.tip.domini.impl.ClauSubjecte@1f,
    HISTORIC,
    EXECUTIVA
);
-> at cat.base.gpt.ui.ConsultaDeutesTest.comprovarCercaBuuida(ConsultaDeutesTest.java:114)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

        at cat.base.gpt.ui.ConsultaDeutesTest.comprovarCercaBuuida(ConsultaDeutesTest.java:114)
```

I really don't understand what i'm doing wrong.ty.

code @beforMethod

```
@BeforeMethod
public void prepararDadesResposta(){
        IDeute dExe, dVol;
        context = new MockExternalContext();
        respostaDeutesExe = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<IDeute>());
        respostaDeutesVol = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<IDeute>());
        respostaDeutesTots = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<IDeute>());

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + 1000; 
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end){
            dExe = new Deute();
            dExe.setAdrecaCompletaCom("Això és un prova.");
            dExe.setAdrecaCompletaTrib("Això és un prova.");
            dExe.setCarrerTrib("Això és un prova.");
            dExe.setCasaTrib("Això és un prova.");
            dExe.setClauDeute(null);
            dExe.setClauObjecte("clauObjecte");
            dExe.setDataTerminiFi(new Date());
            dExe.setDataTerminiIni(new Date());
            dExe.setDesEns("descripcioEns");
            dExe.setDesExp("descripcióExp");
            dExe.setDesTribEn("english");
            dExe.setDesTribEs("spanish");
            dExe.setDesTributCa("catalan");
            dExe.setEscalaTrib("escalaTrib");
            dExe.setIdEns(null);
            dExe.setImportTotal(new Double(0.0));
            dExe.setNifSubjecte("nifSubjecte");
            dExe.setNomSubjecteRaoSocial("nomSubjecteRaoSocial");
            dExe.setPeriodeDeute(EPeriodeDeute.EXECUTIVA);
            dExe.setPisTrib("pisTrib");
            dExe.setPortaTrib("portaTrib");
            dExe.setRefCadastral("refCadastral");
            dExe.setSgTrib("sgTrib");
            dExe.setSituacioDeute(null);
            dExe.setTipusDeute(ETipusDeute.HISTORIC);

            dVol = new Deute();
            dVol.setAdrecaCompletaCom("Això és un prova.");
            dVol.setAdrecaCompletaTrib("Això és un prova.");
            dVol.setCarrerTrib("Això és un prova.");
            dVol.setCasaTrib("Això és un prova.");
            dVol.setClauDeute(null);
            dVol.setClauObjecte("clauObjecte");
            dVol.setDataTerminiFi(new Date());
            dVol.setDataTerminiIni(new Date());
            dVol.setDesEns("descripcioEns");
            dVol.setDesExp("descripcióExp");
            dVol.setDesTribEn("english");
            dVol.setDesTribEs("spanish");
            dVol.setDesTributCa("catalan");
            dVol.setEscalaTrib("escalaTrib");
            dVol.setIdEns(null);
            dVol.setImportTotal(new Double(0.0));
            dVol.setNifSubjecte("nifSubjecte");
            dVol.setNomSubjecteRaoSocial("nomSubjecteRaoSocial");
            dVol.setPeriodeDeute(EPeriodeDeute.VOLUNTARIA);
            dVol.setPisTrib("pisTrib");
            dVol.setPortaTrib("portaTrib");
            dVol.setRefCadastral("refCadastral");
            dVol.setSgTrib("sgTrib");
            dVol.setSituacioDeute(null);
            dVol.setTipusDeute(ETipusDeute.HISTORIC);

            //Carreguem exe
            respostaDeutesExe.add(dExe);
            //Carreguem vol 
            respostaDeutesVol.add(dVol);
        }
//Carreguem tots
respostaDeutesTots.addAll(respostaDeutesExe);
respostaDeutesTots.addAll(respostaDeutesVol);

}
```

this is context code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mockito="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mockito.org/spring/mockito https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/raw/tip/springockito/src/main/resources/spring/mockito.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="cat.base.gpt.ui" />
    <!-- mock del serveis que podem atacar per solicitar info -->
    <mockito:mock id="serveiSubjecte" class="cat.base.tip.service.ISubjectesService"/>
    <mockito:mock id="serveiTip" class="cat.base.tip.service.ITipService"/>
    <mockito:mock id="serveiGpt" class="cat.base.gpt.domini.service.IGptService"/>
    <mockito:mock id="sessio" class="cat.base.baseframe.session.IBaseSession"/>
    <mockito:mock id="usuari" class="cat.base.baseframe.user.IBaseUser"/>
    <!--  
        <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="classpath:cat/base/bfp/ui/applicationResources" />
        </bean>
    -->
    <bean name="consultaDeutes" class="cat.base.gpt.ui.ConsultaDeutesTest"/>

    <bean id="consultaDeutesHandler" class="cat.base.gpt.ui.handler.ConsultaDeutesHandler">
    <property name="serveiSubjecte" ref="serveiSubjecte" />
    <property name="gptServiceBO" ref="serveiGpt"/> 
    <property name="sessio" ref="sessio"/>  
    <property name="usuari" ref="usuari"/>  

</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: The message means you expected some behaviour - by using `verify` - but it didn't happen. I can't see where you are exercising the object under test, is this all the code?

Comment: there is somemethod before, i'll post ty.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't see what is invoking the expected methods on `serveiGpt`, e.g. what is calling `serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(...)` etc...?

Comment: consultaDeuteshandler have an object (IGptService) and invoke the method obtenirDeutes(), maybe i really don't understand how mockito works...ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the message means you expected some behaviour by using `verify` but it didn't happen.

The intent of your test is still a little unclear to me but if you are trying to test `serveiGpt` then you should definitely not be mocking it, instead you should be mocking it's collaborators, invoking `serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(...)` and then verifying calls made to the collaborators.

However, if your intention is to test the handler (mentioned in your comments) then you seem to be missing the piece of code that invokes the handler in your test, it would look something like the following:

```
@Test
public void comprovarCercaBuuida(){
    // arrange
    DeuteBackBean deuteBB;

    List<IDeute> respostaDeutesExe = new ArrayList<IDeute>();
    List<IDeute> respostaDeutesVol = new ArrayList<IDeute>();
    List<IDeute> respostaDeutesTots = new ArrayList<IDeute>();

    Mockito.when(serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT),Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS),Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_EXE))).thenReturn(respostaDeutesExe);
    Mockito.when(serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT),Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS),Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_VOL))).thenReturn(respostaDeutesVol);
    Mockito.when(serveiGpt.obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT),Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS),Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_TOTS))).thenReturn(respostaDeutesTots);

    // act
    handler.handle(...); // <-- invoking the handler with fictional name

    // assert
    Mockito.verify(serveiGpt,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).obtenirDeutes(Mockito.eq(CLAU_SUBJECTE_BUIT), Mockito.eq(E_TIPUS_DEUTE_HIS), Mockito.eq(PERIODE_DEUTE_EXE));
    //Mockito.verify(serveiPersones,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).cercarPersones(Mockito.eq(PATRO_CERCA_AMB_RESULTATS), Mockito.any(IPager.class));
    //Mockito.verify(serveiPersones,Mockito.atLeastOnce()).cercarPersones(Mockito.eq(PATRO_CERCA_AMB_RESULTATS), Mockito.any(IPager.class));
}
```

To make things a bit clearer I've used the [arrange-act-assert pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) to structure your test.

Whilst this might not completely answer your question, I hope it helps in someway.

Comment: ty for your time, i carry on reading and trying to understand. I hope can help you someday.

Comment: No problem, for more about Mockito this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1404824/69875) has some links to resources.